# why is there no rectangle drawn? opencv/pyqt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, opencv3.0

Executing the code I get opencv window with converted image, I get
starting and ending pix position printed but the rectangle does not
appear on the image. Why is that?

```
import sys from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic import cv2

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('now.ui', self)
        self.show()
        self.open.clicked.connect(self.dialog)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.dialog)

    def do_sth(self):
        print('works fine')

    def matp(self, name):
        image = Image.open(name).convert("L")
        arr = np.asarray(image)
        plt.imshow(arr, cmap='Greys_r')
        plt.show()

    def dialog(self):
        self.fileDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
        file_name = self.fileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.label.setText("File Path: " + str(file_name))
        self.print_sth(file_name)

    def print_sth(self, name):
        mode = True
        box1 = []
        box2 = []

        def interactive_drawing(event, x, y, flags, param):

            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if len(box1) is not 0:
                    box1.pop(0)
                b1 = x, y
                print('Start Mouse Position: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y))
                box1.append(b1)

            elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                if len(box2) is not 0:
                    box2.pop(0)
                print('End Mouse Position: ' + str(x) + ', ' + str(y))
                b2 = x, y
                box2.append(b2)
                if mode == True:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (box1[0]), (box2[0]), (255, 255, 255), 1)

        img = cv2.imread(name, 0)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)

        cv2.setMouseCallback('image', interactive_drawing)

        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()




    def close_application(self):
        sys.exit()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PS. The sole `interactive_drawing` function works as intended when I put it alone in a new file.

Comment: This is a really bad way to provide your code, anyone wishing to run it must *manually* remove the `>` characters. Do everyone a favor here, edit your question and *remove the `>` characters since they aren't needed*.

Comment: Sorry, Im new here and didnt think about it;p